# Highstock highchart with external datepicker in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using highstock compare multiple series chart. The default date picker doesn't contain calendar picker and even no validations applied on it. I would like to add react-datepicker or material UI date picker to anything possible. But only the Jquery UI solutions are available on the internet. Could you please help how to achieve this in reactjs. Below is my code and URL of the chart is https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import Chart3 from '../../assets/img/chart3.jpg'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';


class DashboardBuyingTrends extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}

render() {
    const options = {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true
        },

        series: [
            {
                "name": "Spends",
                "data": [
                    [
                        1147651200000,
                        23.15
                    ],
                    [
                        1147737600000,
                        23.01
                    ],
                    [
                        1147824000000,
                        22.73
                    ],
                    [
                        1147910400000,
                        22.83
                    ],
                    [
                        1147996800000,
                        22.56
                    ],
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Savings Generated",
                "data": [
                  [
                    1147651200000,
                    67.79
                  ],
                  [
                    1147737600000,
                    64.98
                  ],
                  [
                    1147824000000,
                    65.26
                  ],
                  [
                    1147910400000,
                    63.18
                  ],
                  [
                    1147996800000,
                    64.51
                  ],
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Realised Savings",
                "data": [
                  [
                    1147651200000,
                    376.2
                  ],
                  [
                    1147737600000,
                    371.3
                  ],
                  [
                    1147824000000,
                    374.5
                  ],
                  [
                    1147910400000,
                    370.99
                  ],
                  [
                    1147996800000,
                    370.02
                  ],
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="spend_chart_title_filters">
                <h5>Buying Trends</h5>
                <div className="spend_filter">
                    {/* <DatePicker
                        className="sk-input-filter"
                        placeholderText="From"
                        filterDate={this.isAfterEndDate}
                        selected={this.state.startDate}
                        // startDate={this.state.startDate}
                        // endDate={this.state.endDate}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
                    /> */}
                    <span className="spend_filter_selected">All</span>
                    <span>ITES</span>
                    <span>Stationary</span>
                    <span>Office Supplies</span>
                    <span>Premius</span>
                    <span>Promos</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="savings_count">
                <div>
                    <p>Savings generated so far</p>
                    <h5>USD 28 Millions</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Savings realised so far</p>
                    <h5>USD 15.28 Millions</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Unrealised savings so far</p>
                    <h5>USD 12.28 Millions</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="chart_div">
                <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    constructorType={'stockChart'}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
  }
export default DashboardBuyingTrends
```

Comment: Have you already seen this: https://whawker.github.io/react-jsx-highcharts/examples/CustomComponent/index.html ?